# Error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import the data from another file and using that in a function but getting error:

Door_position_pattern_actual = Door_Position[d]

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Code References:

```
reactive_sampling_period_in_seconds = 10 * 60

Door_Position = list()

while 1:

    line = f.readline()
    vals = f.readline()
    vals= vals.rstrip()
    data1 = []
    for v in vals.split(","):
        data1.append(v.lstrip())
    if(entry[1]=="DoorPosition"):
        Door_Position = list(data1)

def door_positin_fnc_actual(self, time_in_seconds):

    time_period_in_10mins = 6
    index = int(math.floor(time_in_seconds%(144*reactive_sampling_period_in_seconds)/(reactive_sampling_period_in_seconds)))
    for d in Door_Position :
        Door_position_pattern_actual = Door_Position[d]
    return Door_position_pattern_actual[index]
```

Output References:

```
print(Door_Position)

['(1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1)']
```

I am suspecting (1 is creating prob but not able to fix it, Kindly suggest me ...!!!

Comment: it seems your Doors_Position is a list of strings, yet you get the elements from this list (the d in the for cycle) and try to do Door_Position[d]. Your logic is flawed

Answer (score 1):

This is all wrong:

> ```
> for d in Door_Position :
>     Door_position_pattern_actual = Door_Position[d]
> ```

`d` is not an index, it's a value.
So it doesn't make sense to use it in `Door_Position[ ... ]`

The error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` most probably comes from here.

Perhaps you were looking for something like this:

```
for d in range(len(Door_Position)) :
    Door_position_pattern_actual = Door_Position[d]
```

Comment: If I am not using for loop there it's not assigning values to door_position_pattern_actual, getting different error .. Like it's not able to assign (1 to door_position_pattern_actual

Comment: I added to my post, maybe that's what you were looking for?

Comment: It would be more pythonic to do `... = d` instead of `for d in range(len(...)):`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get rid of `(` and `)`characters within your list elements like this:

```
Door_Position = [item.replace('(', '').replace(')','') for item in Door_Position]
```

Your `Door_Position` list should now look like this:

```
['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']
```

Now, Door_Position is a list of strings, for it to work try `Door_position_pattern_actual = Door_Position[int(d)]`

Take a look at this small sample:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> a[1]
2
>>> a['1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> a[int('1')]
2
```

See? I get the same error, as you, when I try to pass a string as a list index.

Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1'

now I am getting error :

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1'

Comment: That's because your first and last value in the list are '(1' and '1)' instead of '1'. I missed that, I'm going to edit the answer.